# How to compare correctly Strings (and objects) in Java?

Tags: java

For a mini game in where the user tries to guess a name. But when I want to compare two text strings just to check if are the same it seems that doesn't work.

```
    final String miName = "Jhon";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess my name: ");

    while (true) {
     String attempt = input.next();
     if(attempt == miName) {
       System.out.println("Congrats!");
       break;
     } else {
       System.out.println("Try it again!");
     }
    }
```

The output:

```
Guess my name:: 
Karl
Try it again!
jhon
Try it again!
Jhon
Try it again!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.equals` in case of `String`.

`==` gives `true` only when both the object's address match (or in case of primitive types).
`Object` class inherently compares the address in the `.equals` method and you need to override the `.equals` method if in case you wish to write your own custom logic for equality of two objects.

Classes like `String`, `Integer`, etc. have their equals already overridden.